# How to know if a user has pressed the Enter key using Python

Tags: python

How to know if a user has pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> using Python ?

For example :

```
user = raw_input("type in enter")
if user == "enter":
    print "you pressed enter"
else:
    print "you haven't pressed enter"
```

Comment: Well if they don't press Enter `raw_input` won't return, so the check seems redundant. What are you trying to achieve? Could you review your syntax and formatting, please? As it stands, that isn't python.

Comment: Hi, sorry i'm a student still at the beginning of the programming learning curve. My task is to create a program which will execute a task only if the user presses the enter key. Also Could you elaborate on whats wrong with the formatting and syntax.

Comment: julienc has fixed the formatting and syntax for you - you were missing a colon and using `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (comparison). `raw_input` will wait until the Enter key is pressed, so is not appropriate for what you are trying to do. Also, `"enter"` is a series of characters, *not* the Enter key.

Comment: You should use \n as enter. It means the newline character.

Answer (score 42):

As @jonrsharpe said, the only way to exit properly the `input` function is by pressing enter. So a solution would be to check if the result contains something or not:

```
text = input("type in enter")  # or raw_input in python2
if text == "":
    print("you pressed enter")
else:
    print("you typed some text before pressing enter")
```

The only other ways I see to quit the `input` function would throw an exception such as:

- `EOFError` if you type `^D`
- `KeyboardInterrupt` if you type `^C`
- ...

Comment: For Python 3.xx, `input` must be used instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: @jeppoo1 you're right, I wrote this back in 2014, when python2 was still a thing :) I've just updated my answer to comply with python3 though!

Answer (score 3):

You have to install a package called getkey

```
from getkey import getkey, keys
print("press enter")
var = getkey()

if var == keys.ENTER:
  print("You pressed enter")
else:
  print("You didnt")
```

It will only take a one character input though

Answer (score -4):

```
user_input=input("ENTER SOME POSITIVE INTEGER : ")
if((not user_input) or (int(user_input)<=0)):    
  print("ENTER SOME POSITIVE INTEGER GREATER THAN ZERO") #print some info
  import sys        #import
  sys.exit(0)       #exit program 
'''
#(not user_input) checks if user has pressed enter key without entering  
# number.
#(int(user_input)<=0) checks if user has entered any number less than or 
#equal to zero.
'''
```